# Can not connect Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 on Mac OSX 10.12.4

Tags: android, macos, android-studio-2.3

I can not use my Android device with Android Studio.

What I have :

- Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, with Android 4.1.1
- Mac OSX 10.12.4 running on Macbook Pro 2011
- Android Studio 2.3.3
- Android File Transfer 1.0

What I tried :

- Enable the debugging option (development options), connecting the device via a USB cable, the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html) said "it just works, skip this step" but it's yet another scam (or marketing gimmick) for me.
- Install Android File Transfer, no luck.
- Using adb, but `adb devices` still doesn't list my device.

Any suggestion or a way for debugging will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a platform for questions related to programming issues. Your question seems to belong to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing the adb driver ?
Here is how to :

```
bash <(curl https://raw.github.com/corbindavenport/nexus-tools/master/install.sh)
```

If you wish to remove them later :

```
bash <(curl https://raw.github.com/corbindavenport/nexus-tools/master/uninstall.sh)
```

Hope it will solve your issue.